# scala sbt test-only parameters are only picked up when run from sbt shell

Tags: scala, sbt, scalatest

I've tagged a few of my slower running tests with a "SlowTest" tag. When I run my test suite from the sbt shell via the following command:

```
test-only * -- -l com.company.tags.SlowTest
```

the 'SlowTest' tests aren't run. However, when I attempt the same from the bash shell via:

```
sbt test-only * -- -l com.company.tags.SlowTest
```

all the tests are run, including the slow ones I'm trying to filter out. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sbt` treats each commandline argument as a separate target to run. You simply need to quote each individual command you wish to run, which means all of the arguments you've provided:

```
sbt "test-only * -- -l com.company.tags.SlowTest"
```

Comment: *forehead slap* I tried that with quotes AFTER 'test-only' but not including 'test-only'. t/y for your help!